# Difference between String[] with and without single quotation marks in debugger?

Tags: java

I'm debugging an application and realized that the debugger displays `String[]` in two different ways, namely these two: `['test'] and [test]`. Those displayed in the second way work for my purpose and the other doesn't.

What's the difference between these two?

Comment: Whoever voted to close, how exactly is that primarily opinion-based?

Comment: What debugger are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like in the first case, the single quote characters are part of the string. Try adding code to remove them.